# Webpack loader test for files without certain part of filename

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack

I keep my tests in the same folder as my components, and I'm trying to apply a webpack loader (`istanbul-instrumenter-loader`) to all files except the ones called exactly `spec.js` or that end with `*Spec.js` (so both `components/SupportPage/spec.js` and `actions/SupportActionsSpec.js` won't get included. I've tried getting a correct RegEx on regextester.com but I can't get it to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try `*[sS]pec.js` and `*/*[sS]pec.js`

Comment: Webpack takes RegEx, not glob...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found it. Writing a single test to include all files, but exclude the specific spec files was maybe the wrong approach, I solved it like this:

```
      {
        test: /.\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)\/|.[sS]pec\.js$/,
        loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter'
      }
```

Comment: You should escape `.` in your regexp: `\.[sS]pec`: `/(node_modules|bower_components)\/|\.[sS]pec\.js$/`

Answer (score 0):

I got here trying to solve a similar problem relating to Angular 2 component styles imported via `styleUrls`. I thought I would add my solution as an extension to the accepted answer for posterity.

This solution distinguishes between component styles needing to be loaded with `to-string-loader` as opposed to the rest of the styles which can be loaded with `style-loader` instead.

If you configure components as follows:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'admin',
    styleUrls: ['./admin.component.scss'],
    templateUrl: './admin.component.html'
})
```

You can use these rules:

```
// For components `to-string-loader`
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
    include: /\.component\.css$/
},

// For non-components `style-loader`
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
    exclude: /\.component\.css$/
}
```